# Guardar un registro para un model con relacion many-to-many

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

estoy intentando crear un metodo para guardar un nuevo registro de alquiler, primeramente lo hice con el Generic AlquilerCreate y lo guarda sin problemas.
pero estoy haciendo mi propio metodo porque necesito enviarle el usuario sin necesidad de ponerlo en el formulario, ademas al campo hora inicio y hora fin calcularlo con respecto a lo que seleccionen en el Select.

Obtengo el error:
Exception Value: "" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Tengo el proyecto en Github si quieren hecharle un vistazo
https://github.com/Jvargas51h5/AlquilerMotos.git

Espero su ayuda
Gracias de antemano!

ESTOS SON MIS MODELOS

```
class Vehiculo(models.Model):

    placa = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cilindrada = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo)
    km_recorrido = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=Decimal('0.00'))
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.descripcion


class Alquiler(models.Model):

    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = timezone.now())
    hora_inicio = models.TimeField()
    hora_fin = models.TimeField()
    cajero = models.ForeignKey(User)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    vehiculos = models.ManyToManyField(Vehiculo)
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("add_alquileres", "Puede crear Alquileres"),
        )
    def __int__(self):
        return self.cliente
    def motos(self):
        return ', '.join([Vehiculo.descripcion for Vehiculo in self.vehiculos.all()])
```

ESTE MI FORMULARIO

```
TIEMPO = (
        ('15 MINUTOS','15 MINUTOS'),
        ('30 MINUTOS','30 MINUTOS'),
        ('1 HORA','1 HORAS'),
        ('2 HORAS','2 HORAS'),
    )

class AlquilerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    tiempo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=TIEMPO, attrs={'class': 
    'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Alquiler
        fields = ('cliente','tiempo','vehiculos')
        widgets = {
            'cliente': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'vehiculos': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Y ESTA ES LA VISTA

```
def Alquiler_crear(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        alquiler = Alquiler()
        cajero = request.user.username
        cliente = request.POST.get('cliente')
        vehiculos = request.POST.get('vehiculos')
        user_model = User()
        user_model.username = cajero
        cliente_model = Cliente()
        cliente_model.nombre = cliente
        alquiler.cajero = user_model
        alquiler.cliente =  cliente_model
        alquiler.vehiculos = vehiculos
        alquiler.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Alquiler creado.')
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('alquiler:alquiler_list'))
    else:
        form = AlquilerForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'alquiler/alquiler_form.html',context)
```

Comment: El error es que estas intentando guardar en el alquiler un cliente, que no has guardado en la base de datos, asegúrate que antes de llamar a `alquiler.save()` hayas llamado a 'cliente_model.save()'...

Comment: Hola German Alzate en efecto el cliente que estoy ingresando si esta registrado en bd, puesto que lo estoy obteniendo de un select que se esta cargando con los clientes registrados

Comment: me compartieron la documentacion https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
al parecer mi problema va en que no estoy creando el alquiler antes de enviarle el objeto vehiculos, tratare de aplicar eso y veo como me va
Saludos!

Comment: Bueno ahora que he aplicado eso me surge otro error
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'cajero'.

crei que el request.user que le estaba enviando era el problema pero he cambiado mi form y mi view para que obtenga el usuario desde el formulario y tampoco lo he conseguido

Comment: Pasa lo mismo con tu usuario cajero, estás enviando un objeto sin crear para guardar, actualiza el código de la pregunta para ayudarte mejor